# creating android jar to include in my application

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I have developed some android application like Phonegap.

I want to make a jar file of it and use it in another application as we do using Phonegap. Include the jar and extend DroidGap.

But I am not able to make the jar.

Please let me know how to create jar using eclipse?

Many thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RightClick on your project -> Export -> type JAR in filter -> next -> finish
```

here you go...

see this [link](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Escottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) for more...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. But I wanted it specific to an android project and use that jar in other android projects like phonegap.b So i may have to avoid androidManifest.xml, strings.xml etc??